# mac bundle app on osx... will user files and application database be stored inside or outside the bundle?

Tags: macos, filesystems, bundle

I am confused about how creating a mac app - inside a bundle - works. It is my first mac adventure, and the information I find on the web is either contradictory, or does not fit with the reality. Here is my story, please help me understand where files need to be placed in - and out - of a mac app bundle.

I am porting an application (written in Qt) from windows and linux to mac.

It works surprisingly well. I made it with a bundle structure:

```
myapplication.app 
   Contents
      Frameworks ---- a bunch of dylibs
      MacOs      ---- the actual app
      Plugins    ---- some
      Resources  ---- myapplication.rc, empty.lproj, qt.conf
      Info.plist
      PkgInfo
```

My application uses a resources database - opened from code, from an installed location, or users can change to a different location... so the database must be accessible using file browser.

The application also reads / writes (and can even drag-and-drop) custom files.

As I am testing it, I set default read/write location for user-created files in `/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/MyCompany/MyProduct/`

I set the database location in the same place.

Temporary bitmaps sent to printer - same place`/tmp` (may use the cups temporary folder)

Is this good and will it work for a bundle application ? I somehow had the illusion that a bundle means that all files created through the app will be stored inside the bundle - that is how things on my iPad seem to work. The path above is clearly not inside the bundle.

Even more, when I tried to place the database in the Resources folder inside the bundle, when browsing to it (after starting the app by clicking the application.app) I was unable to open the app bundle.

Clearly I am confused.

Will the user have access to locations outside the bundle or inside ? Should I create a "Documents" folder inside the "Contents" for the user-created files ? Or should I make the default documents folder `/Users/CurrentUser/Documents/MyCompany/MyProduct/` ?

The same question applies for the resources database... with an extra question mark. I would like to be able to place this database on the system during installation. I would like all users to have access to it (read rights). What would be a good place for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming for mac was definitely a challenge - things are not what they appear to be.

I found that the best location for files are:

- user created files

  /Users/me/Documents/MyCompany/MyProduct/
- configuration files

  /Users/me/.config/MyCompany/MyProduct/something.ini

  /Users/me/Preferences/xxx.plist
- resource files

  /Users/me/Application Support/MyCompany/MyProduct/

  Contents/Resources/
- temporary files - just create using environment variables or specific language commands and they will end up in /tmp